# How to reference a.Net 4.0 COM in a .Net 2.0 App

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0, com, .net-3.5

I had a Problem to use DotNet 4.0 DLL in a DotNet 2.0 Application, googling the Issue showed a [single suitable solution: COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382927/can-i-use-a-net-4-0-library-in-a-net-2-0-application)

Anyway i'm trying to do that now but i keep getting the following Error when i add the reference in my application (the reference is **tlb**):

> The ActiveX type library 'MyLib.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly
>   and cannot be added as a reference. please reference the Assembly directly.

Am i missing anything? its stated on a lot of websites that this option should work:
[Example1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/30/how-to-use-a-net-4-based-dll-from-net-2-based-application.aspx), [Example2](http://jumbloid.blogspot.de/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html)

On the other hand its stated on an [old link of microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/120882/reference-a-com-from-visual-2005) that this option is not possible "By Design"

Any Ideas? Hints?

Home i'm not confusing things.

Thank you.

Comment: I have a lot of code generated by the EF4 which i need to use in my 2.0 Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it would lead to loading the .NET4 runtime in a process where the .NET2 runtime is already loaded - this is not possible by design!
Support for mixing .NET versions in one process was introduced in .NET 4 .

IF you really need to make this work:

- make a native out-of-process COM server which uses that .NET4 DLL
- then use that server from your .NET2 process (NOT the .NET4 DLL directly !)

REMARK - after seeing your comment about EF4:

I strongly recommend to convert your .NET2 application to .NET 4 - anything else will be a real maintainance nightmare!

Comment: If it was up to me i would have done long time ago. Thanx for the answer, but COM has nothing to do with this does it? as i know is COM not framework specific its a common interface that both runtime versions have to implement.

Comment: @O.D COM comes in several falvors (in-process, out-of-process etc.). the only way .NET 2 and access a .NET 4 DLL via COM is if COM is running "out-of-process" as I wrote above.

Comment: @O.D another option would be to use different ORM instead of EF4 use some 3rd-party ORM with .NET 2 support.

Comment: Thanx again, i need to read more about how to make out-of-process COM's in c#.

Comment: But isnt the following link describing exactly the same scenario?, its written by a microsoft MVP, is there any different parts which idont see? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/30/how-to-use-a-net-4-based-dll-from-net-2-based-application.aspx

Comment: @O.D from my POV that is a real maintainance nightmare since you would need to define COM-friendly interfaces and implement them as wrappers (with any conversion needed which I doubt is possible without really big resource problems since EF4 uses .NET4-specific parts of .NET) and hope that it works... the link you provide  basically described a way to workaround limitations setup by MS for very good reasons - so expect this to fail/be unreliable at runtime...