# NumPy/SciPy in c# with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, numpy, scipy

I want to access the NumPy/SciPy libraries from c#.

According to [this site](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net), *"The IronPython ports of NumPy and SciPy are full .NET ports and include custom C#/C interfaces to a common native C core. This means that the full functionality is available not only to IronPython but to all .NET languages such as C# or F# by directly accessing the C# interface objects or sometimes by evaluating IronPython expressions from other .NET languages."*

According to the [instructions for setting up skipy on .net](http://www.enthought.com/repo/.iron/) the first step in installing skipy is *"Download and install IronPython 2.7, **this will require .NET v4.0.**"*.

I am not adverse to installing net4.0, but for development I am currently stuck on Visual studio 2008, which only supports net3.5.

I searched for instructions to get an ironpython version for net3.5, but that approach seems dubious. Is there a way to use the net4.0 version of ironpython for this purpose? (I do not require ironpython working in visual studio 2008, I only want to access the numpy libraries from c#)

Or how hard would it be to build ironpython as well as NumPy/ScyPy for net 3.5? I have to confess that so far I have not even be able to find any hint that the NumPy visual studio port was ever successfully built under vs2008.

What would be the recommended way to get NumPy/SciPy classes in a visual studio 2008 project?

Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382927/can-i-use-a-net-4-0-library-in-a-net-2-0-application If the libraries are COM compatible, this answer should help.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like that aproach would kill all the performance benefits I am hoping to get from NumPy though. If that is the only way to get the 4.0 dlls running, then it looks like I need to get a 3.5 build of NumPy to get a native ndarray in c#