# TlbImp not working

Tags: tlbimp

I have a dll given by a vendor that 4.0 framework and I am on 3.5.  I was told by the vendor that the dll exposes the com interface so I should still be able to use it.  I have both a .dll and .tlb file.  After doing some research I tried using TlbImp but it gives me an error.

The cmd TlbImp.exe myDll.dll says it's not a valid type library.
The cmd TlbImp.exe myDll.tlb says library was assembled from a CLR assembly and cannot be re imported as a CLR assembly.

Any ideas on what the problem is, or another approach I can use to hopefully access the commands in C# 08?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use a .NET 4 component in a .NET 3.5 app?  I don't understand the COM / TLB involvement here, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes the dll is in .NET4 but am trying to use in a .NET 3.5 app.  According to the vendor it should still work because it exposes the com interface.  Never had to do this before so I am not sure exactly how to do it.  Seems that TlbImp would build a dll that I could use in .NET 3.5 but not sure

Comment: Ok I understand.  You might want to go read this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382927/can-i-use-a-net-4-0-library-in-a-net-2-0-application -- they are in a situation similar to you.  However, I think the prefered approach would be to upgrade your app to .NET 4.x, if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Command should be **tlbimp myDll.tlb /keyfile:filename.snk /myDll.dll**

keyfile:filename.snk is optional, use correct tlbimp.exe file which is available in the following directory 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\VersionX

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.110).aspx