# Using a .net4 based dll from .net2 based app not working for website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, com, interop

Given this reference:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-bb141db3

Is it possible to add a .net2/3.5 website (not a web project) project to this solution and make it work with the adapter? I've tried but no luck. I keep getting error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Net4Assembly' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: That's simply a not supported use case.

Comment: This post says otherwise...http://stackoverflow.com/q/2382927/139698 but I'm having a little problem grokking

Comment: why cannot you upgrade your main app to .NET 4.x? Any trick to bypass the limitation is too tough an approach and is not recommended a way to go.

Comment: Would cause big ripples for clients, just trying to exhaust every possibility of a low impact change and take advantage of newer framework.