# How can I use .NET 4.7 assembly in .NET 2 project?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to reference an assembly which is written in .NET 4.7 in a .NET 2.0 project in Visual Studio. I'm aware of a former practical solution to my question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382927/can-i-use-a-net-4-0-library-in-a-net-2-0-application)) but honestly I didn't quite understand that (I even read the solution in CodeProject). I even exported the assembly as COM (using tlbexp.exe), whenever I want to import that (using tlbimp.exe) or add a reference to, I got an error saying that I cannot use an assembly which is exported from a .NET assembly. Could someone please guide me through it from the first place? When I come to COM programming, I'm almost lost.

Comment: Do you mean .net Standard 2? or .net framework 2 which debuted in 2007..

Comment: @TheGeneral .NET 2 Framework, brother.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see is you take the assembly compiled against .NET 4.7 and with COM-visible types and host it into a separate **host** .exe (thus making an *out-of-process* COM server).  You'll need to read-up on this on how to create an OoP COM Server in .NET.

Your .NET 2 client .exe can then refer to the COM types registered by the **host**.  As far as .NET is concerned it is talking to COM.  The fact that it is .NET 4.7 under the hood is incidental.

You will end up with two processes talking to each other over a COM "wire".  COM is a binary protocol and is language independent.

> I even exported the assembly as COM (using tlbexp.exe), whenever I want to import that (using tlbimp.exe) or add a reference to, I got an error saying that I cannot use an assembly which is exported from a .NET assembly.

You would not have been able to to this because you are mixing a .NET 2 process  with 4.7 types (in-process COM).  That's why we went out-of-process.

Remember, your .NET client will have to add a *COM-reference* and *not* a .NET *assembly reference*.  Treat everything as COM and it could work.

**Note:**

- As per [TheGeneral's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/thegeneral) point below, you may need to ensure that the .NET 2 CLR is installed on the client machine as well as .NET 4.7

Comment: Also might need to have the v2 CLR installed as well